# FTP uploading in BASH script

Tags: bash, ftp, upload

**I need to upload the entire content of a directory /home/test to my ftp server, in a specific folder.**
I will then schedule the script hourly via cron.
Any examples?

NB. consider that I'm on a Netgear ReadyNAS Duo (a debian box) and I can't install lftp or similars, only standard commands :)

Comment: What do you mean "standard commands"?  Bash has no "standard command" for ftp.

Comment: Is the Netgear ReadyNAS Duo the machine you want to copy from or to?  You are unable to install any sort of software or run scripts on it?  Is there a possibility of initiating the connection on the FTP server and pulling down the files?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found this bash script online that has quality documentation:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST=ftp.server.com  #This is the FTP servers host or IP address.
USER=ftpuser             #This is the FTP user that has access to the server.
PASS=password          #This is the password for the FTP user.

# Call 1. Uses the ftp command with the -inv switches. 
#-i turns off interactive prompting. 
#-n Restrains FTP from attempting the auto-login feature. 
#-v enables verbose and progress. 

ftp -inv $HOST << EOF

# Call 2. Here the login credentials are supplied by calling the variables.

user $USER $PASS

# Call 3. Here you will change to the directory where you want to put or get
cd /path/to/file

# Call4.  Here you will tell FTP to put or get the file.
put test.txt

# End FTP Connection
bye

EOF
```

After configuring and saving the .sh script, make it executable:

chmod +x ftpscript.sh

Lastly, configure your cronjob

Comment: this stores the password in plain text in your script. a better solution would be:
    `user $USER`
ftp will then prompt for a password.

Comment: @expz I'm not sure how having the terminal prompt for a password is compatible with scheduling it to run hourly in a cron job...

Comment: I didn't notice. In that case, 
`chmod a-rw+x ftpscript.sh` 
would be a tiny bit of security. A more involved solution would use the default SSH key for security: 
`$PASS=<decrypt a host.conn file using SSH key>; echo user = $USER:$PASS | curl --disable-epsv --ftp-skip-pasv-ip --digest --anyauth --ftp-ssl -K - -T /path/to/file /path/to/remote/dir`

Answer (score 8):

command in one line:

```
ftp -in -u ftp://username:password@servername/path/to/ localfile
```

Comment: Is there a similar comment to list or download files

Answer (score 8):

`curl` is capable of uploading file(s) to FTP servers.

```
curl -T "$FILE(s)" -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD $SERVER/$DIR/
```

You can also use a glob pattern for `$FILE`.

Answer (score 2):

if you have 'curl', which is fairly standard, it can do unattended FTP uploads (see man page for the -T option)

Answer (score 0):

If ssh is installed and configured to allow file transfers you could use `scp`.

If not `netcat` or `rsync` may be an option.

Comment: no way. I have to make it work with ftp.

Answer (score 0):

In a bash script you should be able to do something like:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "
    verbose
    open 1.2.3.4
    USER ftpuser ftppasswd
    put /path/to/stuff.tar.gz
    bye
    " > ftp -n > ftp_$$.log
```

Tarring your directory first would be a good idea and make it much simpler. Also, depending on the size of your directory and the speed of your network, you may want to consider doing differential tars.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to install or build programs, a utility called [ftpsync](http://www.awk-scripting.de/cgi-bin/wiki.cgi/scripting/FtpSync) may be just what you are looking for.  [I've never tried it, and there seem to be several utilities either called that or something very similar.]